# Find common words within two list

Tags: r, list, text-mining, intersect

```
x1 <- c("I like apple", "she enjoys reading")
x2 <- c("he likes apple", "Mike wants to read this book")  
w1 <- strsplit(x1, " ")
w2 <- strsplit(x2, " ")
```

I get two lists:

```
w1  
[[1]]  
[1] "I"      "like"   "apple"  

[[2]]  
[1] "she"      "enjoys" "reading"

w2  
[[1]]  
[1] "he"    "likes"  "apple"

[[2]]  
[1] "Mike"  "wants" "to"    "read"  "this"  "book"
```

I want to get

```
intersect(w1[[1]], w2[[1]])
intersect(w1[[2]], w2[[2]])
```

Suppose the lengths of `w1` and `w2` are very large, thus using for loop is not an efficient way. is there any more convenient way to get the corresponding intersect?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can use `Map` for appylying functions on corresponding elements

```
Map(intersect, w1, w2)
#[[1]]
#[1] "apple"

#[[2]]
# character(0)
```

---

Or using `pmap/map2` from `purrr`

```
library(purrr)
pmap(list(w1, w2), intersect)
```